# SharePoint Content Query Web Part question

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I'm trying to display "Announcement" list using CQW but there is a bullet coming in front of every document. I've tried finding using "IE developer tool" but don't see any `<li>` tags.How to remove this ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the tool pane for the Content Query web part. Expand the Presentation section. Under Styles > Item Style, what is selected? Is it Bulleted title? If it is, try switching to Title only.

Comment: I've tried all the options but nothing works..Bullets are still there :(

Comment: What Item Style are you currently using? Do you have a custom stylesheet that would add the bullets?